# Validate pull request with jenkins in VSTS

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, pull-request, azure-pipelines

The only workaround we found for validating pull requests in visual studio online currently is to create a visual studio build definition that triggers our jenkins job, and create a branch policy on that build definition.

But Visual Studio online is able to trigger the jenkins job directly when a git pull request is created / updated.

Is it possible to create a branch policy on the outcome of that jenkins job? The TFS plugin already provides status feedback for the "normal push" build status.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible now, I submit a user voice here: [Branch policy based on jenkins job](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18925984-branch-policy-based-on-jenkins-job), you can vote and follow up it.