# Automatically build and validate VS Team Services git pull requests on local jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days. I have built successfully my project on Team Services git repository with all tests included, but I was unable to validate my pull requests automatically. Anyway, here' s my project configuration: 
https://snag.gy/d49iaL.jpg
https://snag.gy/jWuMNf.jpg

The part that confused me is what should i write in Refspec field for this particular project.
NOTE: I have to do this without service hooks if there's any chance.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible with TFS for now, where Jenkins could not signal the result of the build which shows up in the code view of the branch.

> **Supporting Pull Requests**
>
> With the "GitHub" or "Bitbucket" Branch Sources, Multibranch Pipelines
>   can be used for validating pull/change requests. This functionality is
>   provided, respectively, by the GitHub Branch Source and Bitbucket
>   Branch Source plugins. Please consult their documentation for further
>   information on how to use those plugins.
>
> [Source Link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#supporting-pull-requests)

Also take a look at this similar question:[Validate pull request with jenkins in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374234/validate-pull-request-with-jenkins-in-vsts) and you could vote up the related uservoice to get more attention.